# Quote about serving to someone better than you

Tags: reference-request, socrates

I remember reading something along the lines of "what can be better than to serve to someone who is better than you" in my philosophy class back in the days. I was pretty sure that I read that in the Trial of Socrates until I wasn't able to find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first approximation...

Plato, [*Apology*, 29b](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0170%3Atext%3DApol.%3Asection%3D29b):

> But I do know that it is evil and disgraceful to do wrong and to disobey him who is better than I, whether he be god or man.

Comment: That should be it 